# Chroot in to reinstall Grub2 reinstall, mnt/ is empty

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, grub2, chroot

I have a common problem: I installed Fedora 18 on my PC that has Windows on it. When I start the PC I don't get asked which system I want to boot, Windows is chosen always.

So I found out that I have to reinstall Grub2. So I booted from a Live CD and entered rescue mode (hit <kbd>e</kbd> in Grub2 and added `single` to the line that begins with "linux..").

Then I should do `chroot /mnt/sysimage`, but there is no such directory. When I do `cd mnt` and `ls`, it is empty. So I have no idea how to change root. When I do `fdisk -l`, the Fedora instalation is in partition `/dev/mapper/fedora-root`.

How can I correctly chroot into the Fedora installation and reinstall Grub2?

Comment: Rescue mode cuts off some of the starting scripts, thus that might be the reason your `/mnt/sysimage` doesn't exist. Are you sure that `/dev/mapper/fedora-root` is your installation? It rather sounds like the root of Live CD to me.

Comment: any idea what to add, to fix mounting /mnt/sysimage?
it is, I remember selecting 40GB partition when I installed fedora into HD. When i do 'fdisk -l', 40GB partition is named /dev/mapper/fedora-root

Comment: I posted the answer assuming you're right about it. If you're stuck at some point, post it in comments.

Answer (score 7):

First thing to do is to ensure you are able to use the Internet in your mode, as you might need it in case that your installed system doesn't contain grub. Typical way for wired connection is to list your interfaces:

```
ifconfig -a
```

choose one that connects you to the Internet (you should be able to tell, it's probably named `eth0` or `em0`) and run `dclient` on it like this:

```
dhclient eth0&
```

Next thing to do is to mount your partition that contains your installed Fedora. Make a mount point for your partition and mount it there:

```
mkdir /mnt/fedora
mount /dev/mapper/fedora-root /mnt/fedora
```

If you have a boot partition (you'd know if you had), you should mount it, too. You can check if you need whether `grep /boot /etc/fstab` gives you any output. If it gives something like `/dev/sda1` as a first column, you should do:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/fedora/boot
```

Then bind some important directories - go to `/mnt/fedora` first, to not overtype:

```
cd /mnt/fedora
mount -o bind /dev dev
mount -o bind /proc proc
mount -o bind /sys sys
mount -o bind /run /run
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs tmp
```

And finally chroot:

```
chroot /mnt/fedora
```

Now you should check your `/boot` directory contents. Does it have some files named `vmlinuz`, `initrd`, `grub` directory with `grub.cfg` in it? If so, good, you can just install grub - assuming your drive you want it to install to being /dev/sda it would be:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

If it doesn't work, you'll have to install GRUB using `yum install grub` (I don't know the exact package name, though). If you don't have grub.cfg file, then run:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

You might install GRUB again for being sure.

Comment: I have grub2.cfg in /boot directory, I can install it directly. I will try it in an hour, thanks for advice for now

Comment: Yeah, the locations might be different between distributions.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the mount point. Fixed.

Comment: wow, I did everything, but notebook is still booting windows automatically...

Comment: when i do 
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub2.cfg
I get following:

Generating grub.cfg ...
   (sda4) can't find ext4 filesystem
   (sda4) can't find ext4 filesystem
   (sda4) can't find ext4 filesystem
   can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sda4
   (sda4) bogus member of reserved sectors
   (sda4) bogus member of reserved sectors
found windows recovery enviroment (loader) on /dev/sda2
done

and when I reboot, windows is booted automatically again..

Comment: when I do ls /boot before I reboot after finishing everything, there are: EFI grub2

Comment: maybe that's the problem, because when I go to bios, i can choose only LEGACY and UEFI at boot options, but fedora seems to be EFI, it is the problem?

Comment: It could work with legacy setting, but I'm not sure for UEFI, I don't have much experience with it. Have you partitioned your drive as GPT one?

Comment: I don't know whats GPT, I just unaloccated 40GB of space and let fedora instalation to format it as it wants - I passed 40gb of unaloccated space to instalator

Comment: here is my fdisk -l:
http://i.imgur.com/70eVdsl.jpg?1

Comment: one partition is GPT but I have no idea, what it is

Comment: now I will try this guide: http://superuser.com/questions/549514/how-to-dual-boot-fedora-18-and-windows-8/549534#549534

Comment: First line of your `fdisk -l` says that you're using GPT. My experience is useless there.